# ElasticSearch composite ID

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-py to insert data. Currently, my `_id` field is something like this:

```
_id: "{'hostname': 'xxxxx', 'day': '2016-03-22', 'service': 'xxxxxxxx'}"
```

My manager told me this is not a good id. I think it's ok.
With ElasticSearch, can i have an id composed of several attributes ?

Eg:

```
_id: {
    hostname: "xxxxxx",
    day: "2016-03-22",
    service: "xxxxxxxx"
}
```

A second solution is to encode my string in base64 with python.

Comment: I would not use that. perhaps make a hash out of these values and then store it.

Comment: Yes i think a hash it's good. And what do you think about base64 ? it's good too?

Comment: Make sure to always normalize the string, though, i.e. remove all spaces, lowercase the string, and put the properties always in the same order (hostname, day, service)